# What "self" is being returned in objective-c init methods?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        // initialize instance variables here
    }

    return self;
}
```

Having read Apple's documentation, I still am confused by the above. I am familiar with the concept of `self` and `this` in other languages, but here we are assigning `self` to superclass init `self = [super init];` then checking if that returned nil or not. But then we are returning self in the last line. I mean, usually returning `self` means "I am returning myself" but here since we assigned `self` to `super init` earlier, aren't we returning `super` as `self` instead of `ourselves` as `self`?

Edit - I have tried to be as clear as possible above but using self in a sentence is tricky. Hopefully, someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No!

Every initializer must call `[super init]`. This means the super initializer you are calling in your example does the same.

All these initializers can prepare the object as they need to do, so that it finally is ready to be used as the class inheritance describes it. They all work on the same object. (That's the point of OO. An object can do everything its (super)classes describe. So all (super)classes must initialize the object.)

`self` is nothing more than a pointer to the object the method/initializer is currently working on. It does not have a special meaning like  "I am returning myself".

Be aware of that no `init` method allocates the object. This done with `[AClass alloc]`.

Comment: ah, i get it now. thanks idmean and micheal welch. So self is the object that is calling these inherited inits even if the inits belong to the parent class, and these inherited inits refer to the calling object (child object that needs to be initialized) as self. Got it!

Answer (score 0):

`self` is the same as `this` in Java or C#.

The line

```
self = [super init];
```

is allowing the parent class to do it's initialization first. If everything is good (in other words, `self != nil`) then we can do any initialization we need to do.

Finally we return `self`.

You have to remember that `self` or `ourselves` as you describe it is made up of the initialization done by the parent class and this class.

**Update**

This class and parent class need to cooperate to initialize `self`. We need to give the parent class first shot by calling `[super init]`. When it's done it returns an object that we refer to as `self`. We then further initialize `self` with the values for the instance variables that this child class defines. But both initializers are working on the same object.

Comment: There is also a difference between allocation and initialisation, and class clusters tie into this as well.

Comment: what i dont understand is that when the parent returns self, they are returning themself. But when we return self, we are returning parent as well since we assigned our self to parent earlier when we did self = [super init]  . NO?

Comment: @Wain Yes, that is correct. The poster seems to be confused and thinking that the parent class is creating one object and this class is creating a different one and we are returning the parent object not this object. I was mainly trying to point out that both the parent init and this init are working on initializing the same object.

Comment: @PrinceSha the parent class and this class are working together to initialize `self`. They are both initializing instance variables of the same object named `self` in this case.

Comment: It's usually the same object, but (one of) the superclass could decide to create a different instance, initialise and return that - that's why you assign self to the result of calling super. If you pass no parameters to `init` then it's highly unlikely to happen, but any superclass has the right to return a different instance (or nil) if it sees fit.

Comment: thanks Wain! appreciate it. Once my points to over 15, I will come back here and up vote the comments

Answer (score 0):

Let me put this in layman's language.

You must have read about Cars and how a Prius is an object of `Car` when studying object oriented programming.
You basically have a superclass `Car` from which all cars inherit, like Prius, Focus, etc. For Prius to be a car, in object oriented terminology, and inheritance, Prius must first inherit from `Car`, and then add Prius specific attributes/properties.

Same way, every class you make in Objective-C (and pretty much every object oriented programming language), you must first inherit from a parent class. The root class being `NSObject` (objective-c).

`[super init]` initializes the parent class, with all it's properties. After that is successful, you add your own attributes/properties, specific to your class.

A common example is when you override the `init` method when subclassing a `UITableViewCell`.

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (self) {

        UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Foo"]];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50);
        [self.contentView addSubview:imageView];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Here, `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` is overridden. It first calls `[super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]`. This initializes a default `UITableViewCell` with the `style` and `reuseIdentifier` supplied to it. You have access to all properties of `UITableViewCell` here. Additionally, an imageView is added to the cell, which is specific to this cell only.

The [`Object Initialization`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html) document is really good to help understand this.